# Convert date string of one time zone to date object in local time Swift

Tags: swift, date, nsdate, nsdateformatter

I want dateString in this format `"2016-12-22T08:00:00-08:00"` to be converted to date object in users local time for example `2016-12-22 21:30:00 +0530` when the users time is +05:30 from UTC

OR

I want dateString in this format `"2016-12-22T08:00"` which is PST time to be converted to date object in users local time for example `2016-12-22 21:30:00 +0530` when the users time is +05:30 from UTC or `2016-12-22 16:00:00 +0000` when the users time is 00:00 from UTC

When I try the below code and print dateObject it prints `Optional(2016-12-22 02:30:00 +0000)` but I want `2016-12-22 21:30:00 +0530` since my local time is +05:30 from UTC.

```
let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss-08:00"
dateFormatter.timeZone = NSTimeZone.local

let dateString = "2016-12-22T08:00:00-08:00"
let dateObject = dateFormatter.date(from: dateString)
print("dateObject \(dateObject1)")
```

Comment: Not sure why its being down voted when the question is clear and when there is no similar one on SO.

Comment: I didn't down vote  but there are hundreds of nearly identical questions. Nothing you are asking hasn't been asked over and over before.

Comment: BTW, why do you care what timezone the resulting ISO 8601 date string shows? This timezone is _not_ part of the the `Date` object. Most people will actually use GMT/UTC/Zulu to avoid precisely this sort of confusion...

Comment: You can forestall down-votes by illustrating what research you've done and describe how precisely your question is different.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fix your `dateFormat` to:

```
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZZZZZ"
```

Remove the `timeZone` line. It's not needed since your date string specifies its own timezone.

```
dateFormatter.timeZone = NSTimeZone.local // remove this line
```

Now your code works fine.

*"But wait, the output of `print(dataObject)` isn't what I want"*

Yes it is. Like thousands before you, you misunderstand the output of printing a `Date` object.

If you wish to view a `Date` in the local timezone, in a given format, use a `DateFormatter` to convert the `Date` into a `String`. You will get the current, local timezone by default.

```
let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateStyle = .long
dateFormatter.timeStyle = .long
let newString = dateFormatter.string(from: dateObject)
print(newString)
```

And you get just what you wanted.

Comment: Made changes you suggested, It still prints out in UTC time when my time zone is +0530 from UTC. For example it print out `Optional(2016-12-22 16:00:00 +0000)` but I am expecting `Optional(2016-12-22 21:30:00 +0530)`

Comment: Of course. Don't use `print` on a `Date`. It's confusing until you understand what's happening. Use the code I posted in the 2nd half of my answer to get your desired output (of course you are free to change the date/time styles or use a specific format to suit your needs).

Comment: Unrelated, but he may also want to set the `locale` to `en_US_POSIX` on that first formatter that goes from the IS8601/RFC3339 string to the `Date` object, though, as outlined in [Technical Q&A 1480](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/qa/qa1480/_index.html).

Comment: Or you could do:  `let convertedDateString = dateFormatter.string(from: dateFormatter.date(from: dateString)!)`